# Proving Complex Differentiable $f(z)={\overline z}^2$ at $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am trying to prove that $f(z)={\overline z}^2$ is complex differentiable at $z_0=0$.

With $h=h_1+ih_2$, using the definition, we have $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{\overline h}^2}{h}=\lim_{h_1,h_2\to 0}\frac{h_1^2-h_2^2-i2h_1h_2}{h_1+ih_2}$$ and I do not understand how to find this limit. It should exist, and I can use the Cauchy Riemann Equations to prove it does exist, but I woudld like to use the way above, and I don't know why it doesn't work. My brain is fried so maybe I'm missing something obvious, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{h\to 0}|\frac{{\overline h}^2}{h}|=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|^2}{|h|}= \lim_{h\to 0}|h|=0.$

Thus $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{\overline h}^2}{h}=0.$

Comment: Thank you! To be clear, I can arbitrarily add absolute values when using the definition of differentiation or are you using the definition of a limit? (which means you have to know the limit in advance) I would accept, but the system requires I wait 5 minutes before I do, I just upvoted for now :)

Comment: I used: $\lim_{h \to a}g(h)=0 \iff \lim_{h \to a}|g(h)|=0.$ Thanks for upvoting.